# *ngFor is not looping all items

Tags: angular, firebase, ngfor

l am try to build angular project using Firebase database . but the problem is the NgFor is print only first element of out 3 element array in html .

I have following database structure:

[image: rrrrr]

Home ts :

```
ordersstatus:  AngularFireList<any>;
this.af.list("/orders").valueChanges().subscribe((res:any)=>{
  this.ordersstatus = res
})
```

HTML :

```
    <div class="card-body text-center" *ngFor="let cat of ordersstatus; let i=index">

            <tbody *ngFor="let item of cat   | keyvalue">
                <tr>
                  <td>#{{item.value.newproduct[i].item.itemId}}</td>
                  <td>{{item.value.newproduct[i].item.title}}</td>
                  <td><span>{{item.value.status}}</span></td>
                  <td>
                    <div>{{item.value.Tot}}</div>
                  </td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>

    </div>
```

any idea please ?

Comment: Your ngFor loop a cat array! But i don't see on your code this cat array. Can you post it?

Comment: `*ngFor="let cat of ordersstatus; let i=index"`  then  `*ngFor="let item of cat   | keyvalue"` the main array is `ordersstatus`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the HTML template to this:

```
<div class="card-body text-center" *ngFor="let cat of data; let i=index">
  <tbody *ngFor="let item of cat | keyvalue">
    <tr *ngFor="let product of item.value.newproduct">
      <td>#{{product.item.itemId}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</div>
```

Stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z6twbw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to get only first item from the array `ordersstatus`. May be this is what you are looking for

```js
// Variable on your component
countOfStatusesToDisplay = 1;
```

Code on your html template. Check out `slice:0:countOfStatusesToDisplay`

```html
<div class="card-body text-center" *ngFor="let cat of ordersstatus | slice:0:countOfStatusesToDisplay; let i=index">
    <tbody *ngFor="let item of cat | keyvalue">
        <tr>
            <td>#{{item.value.newproduct[i].item.itemId}}</td>
            <td>{{item.value.newproduct[i].item.title}}</td>
            <td><span>{{item.value.status}}</span></td>
            <td><div>{{item.value.Tot}}</div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</div>
```

Comment: No , the ngfor , shows only first item of array , i want to show all items array . check this image . https://i.ibb.co/XzXG1b4/Capture.png . he shows only first array not all of them

Answer (score 0):

On your ts file

```
ordersstatus:  AngularFireList<any>;
  this.af.list("/orders").valueChanges().subscribe((res:any)=>{
  this.ordersstatus = res.newproduct
 })
```

HTML

```
        <tbody *ngFor="let item of ordersstatus | keyvalue">
            <tr>
              <td>{{item.itemId}}</td>
              <td>{{item.title}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

</div>
```